artifacts creality cr6 se
You can't tell what these artifacts do. Somewhere it looks as if the material is missing somewhere, as if there is more of it, maybe as if it is outside the layer. Pulleys and belts in order, bearings in order, I tried another brand of material and it didn't help either. Different print speeds. I also tried the square, it goes around the entire print. Roby it printer creality cr6 se


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
